# porque sale este error en java, Cannot format given Object as a Date?

Tags: java, jsf, date

Tengo el siguiente metodo

```
   public List<String> llenaDiasAnioMes() {

    Date date = null;
    List<String> lDias = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Integer i = 1; i <= this.getLongitudMes(); i++) {

        String fechaActual = i.toString() + "-" +mes.toString() + "-"+annio.toString();
        lDias.add(fechaActual);

        DateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
        String fechaString = String.join(", ", lDias);

        System.out.println("PRUBAA LISTA\n" +fechaString);




        try {
            date = inputFormat.parse(fechaString);
            System.out.println("PRUEBA DATE\n" +date);
        } catch (ParseException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(RegistroAccesoComponentImpl.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    return lDias;

}
```

a la lista le paso los dias, el mes y el anio
donde el mes y el anio, los obtengo asi:

```html
 mes = LocalDate.now().getMonth().getValue();
        

        Year año = Year.now();
        annio = año.getValue();
```

Tengo la siguiente tabla

```html
<p:dataTable id="detalle" var="detalle" styleClass="columns" value="#{RegistroAccesoComponent.incidenciaAnioMesDet}" emptyMessage="No se encontraron registros.">

  <p:columnGroup type="header">
    <p:row>

      <p:column headerText="FECHA" style="width:20px;" styleClass="columns" />
      <p:column headerText="ENTRADA" style="width:20px;" styleClass="columns" />
      <p:column headerText="SALIDA" style="width:20px;" styleClass="columns" />
      <p:column headerText="INCIDENCIA" style="width:60px;" styleClass="columns" />
      <p:column headerText="ACCION" style="width:10px;" styleClass="columns" />
    </p:row>
  </p:columnGroup>
  <p:column styleClass="columns">
    <h:outputText value="#{RegistroAccesoComponent.llenaDiasAnioMes()}">
      <f:convertDateTime type="date" pattern="dd-MM-yyyy" />
    </h:outputText>
  </p:column>

  <p:column styleClass="columns">
    <h:outputText value="#{detalle.horaEntrada}">
      <f:convertDateTime type="date" timeZone="CST" pattern="HH:mm:ss" />
    </h:outputText>

  </p:column>
  <p:column styleClass="columns">
    <h:outputText value="#{detalle.horaSalida}">
      <f:convertDateTime type="date" timeZone="CST" pattern="HH:mm:ss" />
    </h:outputText>
  </p:column>
  <p:column styleClass="columns">
    <h:outputText value="#{detalle.incidencias.cveIdIncidencia}  #{detalle.incidencias.concepto}" />
  </p:column>
  <p:column styleClass="columns">
    <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-search" title="View" onclick="PF('modalIntentos').show();">
    </p:commandButton>
  </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

en la columna de fecha, quiero mostrar los dias correspondientes del mes, en este formato dd/mm/yyyy
como aqui
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y en consola me sale lo siguiente

```html
PRUBAA LISTA
1-3-2018
PRUEBA DATE
Thu Mar 01 00:00:00 CST 2018
PRUBAA LISTA
1-3-2018, 2-3-2018
PRUEBA DATE
Thu Mar 01 00:00:00 CST 2018
PRUBAA LISTA
1-3-2018, 2-3-2018, 3-3-2018
PRUEBA DATE
Thu Mar 01 00:00:00 CST 2018
PRUBAA LISTA
1-3-2018, 2-3-2018, 3-3-2018, 4-3-2018
PRUEBA DATE
Thu Mar 01 00:00:00 CST 2018
```

y sale este error

```html
Could not convert '[1-3-2018, 2-3-2018, 3-3-2018,n] to a string.
Caused By: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot format given Object as a Date
```

y lo que note esque en el print de System.out.println("PRUEBA DATE\n" +date);  sale siemre lo mismo

como puedo solucionar esto, para que me muestre la fecha en el formato correcto?

Comment: Si reemplazas lo que tienes en el pattern de tu f:convertDateTime por esto *dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm* te sigue saliendo lo mismo?

Comment: @Lucas.D, si sale lo mismo

Comment: Estas usando Date de *java.util* ? No es ni de sql ni de JODA?

Comment: si, uso el java.iutil

Comment: El problema es que estás retornando una lista de `String` con la expresión `#{RegistroAccesoComponent.llenaDiasAnioMes()}` y luego le aplicas un `f:convertDateTime` al `outputText`, pero para que funcione el `f:convertDateTime` el valor que retorna la expresión debería ser de tipo `Date`. Mira [este enlace](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/bnasv/index.html)

Comment: @E.Betanzos, ya cheque la documentacion y tengo lo siguiente: <h:outputText value="#{RegistroAccesoComponent.date}" >
                                   <f:convertDateTime  type="date" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy"/>, pero solo me muestra el primer dia, como le hago para mostrar los demas?

Comment: Yo hace mucho que no hago nada en JSF y no te sabría decir si existe algún modo de crear los datos de una columna independientemente del `p:dataTable`, porque recuerda que el funcionamiento de este componente es que itera sobre la lista que le definas como su `value` y para cada elemento te crea una fila. Quizás tengas que crear en tu backing bean una lista donde cada elemento de esta tenga los datos originales unido a los dias del mes.

Comment: @E.Betanzos, gracias

Comment: que relacion tiene cada fila de `incidenciaAnioMesDet` con las fechas que quieres mostrar? No deberia la fecha ser un dato de cada objeto que retorna `incidenciaAnioMesDet`?